# Python - 'function' object has no attribute 'deflPoly'

Tags: python, polynomial-math, deflate

Tried creating a little script to test out the different parts of a script called polyRoots. When I tried to utilize the deflating poly function I get an error. Their is nothing complicated about this code and I am unsure why it isn't working.

```
import polyRoots as pr

print( "Deflation of polynomial: ")
print( pr.polyRoots.deflPoly( [20, -36, 7, 3], -5 ))
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:temp.py", line 13, in <module>
print( pr.polyRoots.deflPoly( [20, -36, 7, 3], -5 ))

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deflPoly'
```

The polyRoots script is a book code resource from numerical methods to engineering. It is as follows:

```
## module polyRoots
''' roots = polyRoots(a).
    Uses Laguerre's method to compute all the roots of
    a[0] + a[1]*x + a[2]*x^2 +...+ a[n]*x^n = 0.
    The roots are returned in the array 'roots',
'''    
from evalPoly import *
import numpy as np
import cmath
from random import random

def polyRoots(a,tol=1.0e-12):

    def laguerre(a,tol):
        x = random()   # Starting value (random number)
        n = len(a) - 1
        for i in range(30):
            p,dp,ddp = evalPoly(a,x)
            if abs(p) < tol: return x
            g = dp/p
            h = g*g - ddp/p
            f = cmath.sqrt((n - 1)*(n*h - g*g))
            if abs(g + f) > abs(g - f): dx = n/(g + f)
            else: dx = n/(g - f)
            x = x - dx
            if abs(dx) < tol: return x
        print('Too many iterations')

    def deflPoly(a,root):  # Deflates a polynomial
        n = len(a)-1
        b = [(0.0 + 0.0j)]*n
        b[n-1] = a[n]
        for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):
            b[i] = a[i+1] + root*b[i+1]
        return b

    n = len(a) - 1
    roots = np.zeros((n),dtype=complex)
    for i in range(n):
        x = laguerre(a,tol)
        if abs(x.imag) < tol: x = x.real
        roots[i] = x
        a = deflPoly(a,x)
    return roots
```

Uncertain what is causing this error as it really is just one line of code for each deflation request. Please advise.

Comment: Elements of both of the current answers are correct and relevant. Names defined inside a function are local to that function and are not exposed outside that function. You seem to be conflating Python functions and classes (or perhaps functions and modules). I don't think you'll get much more detail or explanation than this from Stack Overflow users (not because they don't want to help, but because answering this type of question feels like teaching you the fundamentals of Python); try reading the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he cannot call the function `deflPoly` outside the function. Because it is of `local` scope.

**For ex:**

```
def a():
    print 'a function'
    def b():
        print 'b function'

a().b()
```

This should be error, because function `a()` returns None, If even some value for function `a()` returns, it has no attribute `b`.

Inorder to use function `b()`, we have to setup a `link` to inner function s like

```
def a():
    print 'a function'
    def b():
        print 'b function'
    return b

test = a()
test()

>>>a function
>>>b function
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `polyRoots` is a function; `deflPoly` is a function defined inside of it, but it is not an attribute of it.